# Python desktop widgets

Tags: python, desktop, widget

I'm interested in making desktop widgets, similar to Apple's Dashboard or what Vista has. I'd like to make them cross-platform, if possible. Opera's widgets are cross-platform but require the user to have Opera installed, so that's a big limitation.

I know most widgets are made with HTML/XML, CSS, and Javascript. Is there a way to create them using Python?

---

**Update**: I did find a site talking about [Pyjamas](http://advogato.org/article/981.html). Does anyone have experience with it and, if so, what are its capabilities/limitations?

Comment: For anyone that stumbles upon this in future, Pyjamas is a web framework for writing RIA (rich Internet applications). It's a port of Google's (now discontinued?) GWT.

Answer (score 5):

You should take a look at what the guys at [Digsby](http://www.digsby.com/) are doing. Basically, they've written a port of [WebKit to wxWidgets](http://wxwebkit.wxcommunity.com/), and then use WebKit to render the interface, and wxPython for writing the rest of the app. Pretty neat, but *very* alpha at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/), which will allow you to create desktop widgets, but they won't be managed by OSX's Dashboard.  If you'd like to [develop an OSX widget](http://developer.apple.com/macosx/dashboard.html), you'll want to stick with HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at pyqt4.  It has webkit integration.  I was looking into this myself but haven't really had time to dig into the API.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [gDesklets](http://www.gdesklets.de/). AFAIK they're UNIX only, but mabybe porting them to other platforms make more sense than starting from scratch?

They use python to create widgets (desklets).

Answer (score 0):

[Screenlets](https://launchpad.net/screenlets) is designed for this task.

> The Screenlets project is both a Python framework to simplify writing Cairo-drawn desktop widgets, similar to those found in the "Dashboard" feature of OS:X.

Widgets can be written entirely in Python. [A collection of widgets](https://launchpad.net/indiv-screenlets) using the framework have already been developed.

It is designed to work with Linux desktop. But it should be easy to port to other platforms, since Cairo is cross-platform, in my opinion.

Disadvantages

- It's not updated frequently. The latest version, 0.1.6, was released on 2012-01-27
- Its home page has been down for some time. Launchpad works though.
- Only Python 2 is supported.